# Equivalent of GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX for Intel GPUs?

Tags: c++, opengl

Exist an equivalent of [`GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NVX/NVX_gpu_memory_info.txt) (nvidia) / [`GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ATI/ATI_meminfo.txt) (amd) for the intel dedicated gpus? Or any other way to get this information?

I'm currently using SDL_opengl.h to get those macros but I saw that they also exist in GLEW. Maybe GLEW has the equivalent for intel?

Comment: Considering that those two enumerators are not even equivalents of *each other*, I'm unsure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't help that most Intel graphics solutions use system memory, so questions like "how much graphics memory is available" don't precisely apply.